# Typescript throwing an error for the wrong type even when the type is right

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using a [react youtube package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube) for the first time and I am trying to embed and customise youtube player in a react component:

```
const options = {
  height: 'auto',
  width: '100%',
  playerVars: {
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
    controls: 0
  }
}
```

From the documentation I can see that I am using the right parameters, but if I try to pass them like this:

```
<YouTube videoId="xyQ5qD-u-J7" opts={options} ref={videoElement}/>
```

But, typescript is throwing an error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: YouTubeProps | Readonly<YouTubeProps>): YouTube', gave the following error.     Type '{ height: string; width: string; playerVars: { controls: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Options'.       The types of 'playerVars.controls' are incompatible between these types.         Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0 | 2 | 1 | undefined'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: YouTubeProps, context: any): YouTube', gave the following error.     Type '{ height: string; width: string; playerVars: { controls: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Options'.
```

How is that possible, I am passing a right value for controls 0 and the right type, why is then Typescript throwing an error?
I have tried to import an Options interface:

```
import YouTube, {Options} from 'react-youtube'
```

But, then I got an error:

```
ESLint: Options not found in 'react-youtube'(import/named)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: if you try `import type {Options} from 'react-youtube'` does the eslint error go away? I'd love to help, but when I install that package and give it your exact inputs I'm not receiving any complaints from typescript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hover over `options` you see that typescript has inferred controls' type as `number`.

The way typescript sees `options`, is that the value of `controls` can always be changed.

While it should be `'0 | 2 | 1 | undefined'` and not `number`, if you want to pass to as props.

There are a few ways to pass type checker, for example:

```
const options = {
  height: 'auto',
  width: '100%',
  playerVars: {
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
    controls: 0
  }
} as const
```

`options` is now read-only and the the value of controls is guaranteed to always be the value of its definition (`0`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it, had no idea about this in Typescript!